# Java socket sends only one message

Tags: java, sockets, server, message

I have made a socket in Java.
This socket connects with a server.

When I start my program, the server sends a message that my socket is connected with the AEOS.
When I try to login to the server for sending some commands, then the server responds again with: `status connected to AEOS version`

This is not the message that I expect, normally my server must send a "response true".

Can you help me?

Thanks.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPClient {
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        while(true) {
            String sentence;            
            String modifiedSentence;    

            Socket clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1201);

            BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());        
            BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
            outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
            modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
            System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);

            clientSocket.close();
        }
    }
}
```

[output socket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnpBq.png)

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of console output. You should copy the text and paste it into a code block, by [edit]ing your question.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to read everything that server had sent? Also, need to open a new Socket every-time? Depends on your implementation. Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Socket clientSocket = null;

        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1201);

            BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(
                    clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            String initialMessageFromServer = null;

            while ((initialMessageFromServer = inFromServer
                    .readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(initialMessageFromServer);
            }

            while (true) {
                String sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
                outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');

                StringBuilder modifiedSentence = new StringBuilder();
                String responseFromServer = null;

                while ((responseFromServer = inFromServer.readLine()) != null) {
                    modifiedSentence.append(responseFromServer);
                    modifiedSentence.append('\n');
                }

                System.out
                        .println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence.toString());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (clientSocket != null) {
                try {
                    clientSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I have tried the code but now he connects with the server but when i send a command then notting happens .. Normally after the connection with the server i must enter my login and password. When i enter that my server response with a text. That doesn't happen ..